# Calculate average of values in hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am creating a application for calculating average marks of male and female students in a class

```
 Name class marks gender
  abc   1    20    M
  REF   1    30    F
  def   2    30    F
  xyz   1    40    M
  dsf   3    20    F
  wer   2    10    F
```

I want the final output to be as

```
   class gender  average
    1     M       30 
    1     F       30
    2     F       20
```

i.e class with male and female with thier average

I have created a map with values as input

Key as class and values as the complete student object

Which is better approach
To create two separate maps for female and male
Calculate average and then separately

With only single map

Comment: "Key as class and values as the complete student object". Do you mean a `Map` with key as class and value as a `List` of `Student` objects?

Comment: A single Map will lead to overriding the class all the time

Comment: yes key as class and list of students as values

Answer (score 1):

You might use just one map for that. Please note that the code below is way far from ideal and it will need some refactoring. It is just for demonstration purposes. Lets say we have 2 classes `Student` and `Average`

```
    class Student {
        private String gender;
        private Integer mark;
        private String name;
        // getters & setters
        ...            
    }
    class Average {
        private String gender;
        private Double average;
        // getters & setters    
        ...
    }
```

and we have a map of classes with students

```
Map<String,List<Student>> course = new HashMap<>();
```

now using Stream API we can do something like this

```
Map<String,List<Average>> map = course.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey, e ->
            Arrays.asList(
                    new Average("f", e.getValue().stream().filter(student -> student.getGender().equals("f"))
                            .mapToInt(Student::getMark).average().getAsDouble()),

                    new Average("m", e.getValue().stream().filter(student -> student.getGender().equals("m"))
                            .mapToInt(Student::getMark).average().getAsDouble()))

    ));
```

It will give you a Map with class name, and list of average marks per gender.

```
map.forEach((s, averages) -> {
        System.out.print("class: " + s + " ");
        averages.forEach(average ->
                System.out.print(average.getGender() + " " + average.getAverage() + " ")
        );
        System.out.println();
    });
    // class: 1 f 17.5 m 10.0 
    // class: 2 f 10.0 m 13.5
```

As I said this code just for demonstration purposes, and it need some improvements. Please use it with caution.

Comment: please give solution in java 7 my system does support 8

Comment: @coder25 The idea is the same. You need to iterate over you map, count average for each gender inside one class and then add final result to your map.

Comment: I need to sort them first by key i.e class and then gender